# Printing to Hard-Printer in java with 300dpi

Tags: java, graphics, printing, hardware

Okay, so i just started working on a program that is supossed to print out its graphics. Mine is almost identical to the copyrighted one at Oracle located here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java

---

So basically I am a complete noob and have tried to figure out how to set my page to be 8.5x11in and 300dpi but to no avail :( I dont even have working code on this topic after all my failed attempts. I know it has something to do with `Paper.setSize()` and `PrinterResolution` But i cannot glean enough from the javadocs to understand these. Please help.

EDIT: I believe i discovered that `Paper.setSize(72*8.5,72*11);` Sets the page size to 8.5x11 but the dpi is still 72. This is my code so far.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         Paper pg = new Paper();
        pg.setSize(72*8.5,72*11);
        pf.setPaper(pg);
        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

     /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    //Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    g.drawString("Hello world! :D", 100, 100);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: If you run the Oracle example, does it print?

Comment: Yes but the oracle example is at 72dpi and im not sure what page size it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of the Print Services API.  This allows you to request certain properties for a `PrintJob`, including the DPI.

This is a **RELLAY** basic example...

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));
aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(2, 2, 210 - 4, 297 - 4, MediaPrintableArea.MM));

PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pj.setPrintable(new PrintTask());

if (pj.printDialog(aset)) {
    try {
        pj.print(aset);
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Working with Print Services and Attribues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks! this looks like exactly what im looking for! ill run and play around with it.

Comment: @snocavotia From memory, I think example was set up for A4, but the `MediaPrintableArea` is pretty intuitive so you should be able to adjust it to your needs.  Also not, that if the Print Services API will only list hardware that can support the attributes ;)

Comment: I only encountered one problem while trying to get this to work. I cant seem to find any `PrintTask` class in the javadocs.

Comment: Hahahahaha xD never mind stupid me.. i didnt even notice i need `this` nevermind :P

Comment: `PrintTask` was my `Printable` :P