# I want to know how to do silent printing in Java?

Tags: java, printing

I can't find good informations about silent printing. I want to print without asking user about settings (they should be defined in program). Important is that I don't want to use any libaries. Just SDK. Please, tell me how to do it. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class Main implements Printable, ActionListener {

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Now we perform our rendering */
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

        /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        //boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
        if (true) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
              System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new Main());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Can you define *silent printing*?

Comment: Silent printing: printing without asking user about anything. All settings are in code.

Comment: So ... that is what your code is doing.  (Apart from the bit about setting something.)  So what is your question?

Comment: *"printing without asking user about anything."* That's a great way for a malicious app. to dump 1,000 pages of porn ads to the company printer.

Answer (score 1):

At a very basic level, it might look something like...

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Printable printable = ...;
job.setPrintable(printable);
job.print();
```

This will print to the default printer using the default properties of the printer.

You could also make use of the [`PrintRequestAttributeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet.html) and [`PrintService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html) to modify the printer and/or properties to be used

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029624/java-printing-prints-only-one-page-when-using-book-class/16030160#16030160) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026077/printing-to-hard-printer-in-java-with-300dpi/16026234#16026234)